# Is There a Programatic Way to Clear a FilePicker?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

I am using an ‘<input type="file" . . .’ to pick files, one at a time, and append the selected files to a table, just under the picker.  This behaves fairly similarly to using a SharePoint form’s “Attachment” button on the ribbon.

But, after picking a file, and updating the table, I would like to clear the display of the picker.   Changing `.value = ""`  is ineffective...

I have like:

[image: ScreenShot]

I would like to get rid of that "W:\Documents\HTML Te..." content.

Comment: If you're planning to upload those files, you can't really clear the file control as then you will not be able to upload the file. The usual approach is to hide the filled input field and create a new one.

Comment: I am going to be using JQuery and SPServices to accomplish the upload.  The only thing I am really using the FilePicker for is to get the path and filename.  The string representing the path-n-file that you see in the table, below the picker, is how I am going to get the file.

Comment: But you can't upload an arbitrary file from a browser. This is a security restriction of the browser. The only way to have a file be uploaded is to have the user choose it via a file input. Then you have to either keep that input around, or you may be able to just keep the file object from `files` around. One way or another, you're going to have to keep more than just the path.

Comment: This is no longer true.  With HTML 5 enabled browsers, the JavaScript contains a FileReader class that does allow you to read arbitrary files.  You cannot write to them, but you can read them, encode them in base64, and send them to the server.

Comment: "File objects may be obtained from a FileList object returned as a result of a user selecting files using the <input> element, from a drag and drop operation's DataTransfer object, or from the mozGetAsFile() API on an HTMLCanvasElement." There is no function I see that allows constructing a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) from an arbitrary path. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to delete the input[type=file] element and then create a new one.

```
var el = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var parent = el.parentElement;
var newEl = document.createElement("input");
newEl.setAttribute('type', 'file');
parent.removeChild(el);
parent.appendChild(newEl)
```

Comment: This almost did it.  There is a table in the same td with this file picker, and the answer, above, would put the picker AFTER the table.  The answer, below, was suggested by a co-worker, and works perfectly.

Comment: The answer above was not supposed to be an exact fix as you did not share any of your code. It was only meant to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Because the result needs to be like:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <target picker>
          <Nested table>
            . . .
```

and the`appendChild`solution, from Connor would have resulted in:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <Nested table>   // <———<<<  wrong order
          <target picker>  // <———<<<  for these 2
            . . .
```

it wouldn't work for me.  I started looking at`.insertBefore()`, but a co-worker suggested the JQuery solution, below.  I come in with a reference to the existing FilePicker, passed in as`this` by the onchange event of that existing picker.  (You can see the call in the function added to`newPicker`).  After processing the existing picker for the file name, I run the following:

```
    var newPicker = document.createElement('input');
        newPicker.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        newPicker.style.display = 'block';
        newPicker.onchange = function() { FileSelection(this); };

    $(picker).replaceWith(newPicker);
```